# Flutter onTap with REST call ends in infinity loop

Tags: rest, flutter

I like to create a simple login in Flutter. When running the code, it gets stuck in an infinity loop. I already found out it's "bad practice" to call a REST API within the build method but I don't know how to avoid this.

How can I resolve this problem? What is the best way to handle REST calls from a button press/tap without setting the functionality within the "build" method?

My login view is as followed (details omitted):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _emailPasswordWidget(),
                        PrimaryButton("Login", true, performLogin),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
        )
    );
```

Where the primary button takes a lambda.

```
  void performLogin(BuildContext context) {
    final String userName = _userName.text.trim();
    final String password = _password.text.trim();
    if(password.isEmpty || userName.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    UserService service = UserService();
    service.loginUser(userName, password).then((val) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainLayout()));
    }).catchError((e) {
      showDialog(context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                content: Text("ERROR")
            );
          });
    });
  }
```

This is called by "PrimaryButton" like this:

```
onTap: widget.onTab(context)
```

My problem now is, that whenever I press the "Login" button, it calls the function (for testing, it's Error) and gets stuck in an infinite ERROR loop. When I press somewhere to close the Dialog it gets triggered again. It also seems to be triggered multiple times with one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It's not caused by code but by the used REST request in the `onTab` lambda (`service.loginUser`). The response is taking much longer than expected and therefore, the call does not return correctly.

I use a timeout on the REST request for these kinds of "false" requests to solve the problem.